# Fetching single data returns error

Tags: php, android, sql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch couple of single data in my server database but this is throwing some errors. The incoming data is correct. The search function just don't get completed.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
define('HOST','xxxxxxxxxxx');
define('USER','xxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('PASS','xxxxxxxxx');
define('DB','xxxxxxxxxx');
 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

 $post_id = $_POST['id'];
 $buyer_mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
 $buyer_name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "select mobile from flatowner where id='$post_id'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$owner_mobile = $row['mobile'];



$sql = "select name from user where mobile='$owner_mobile'";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$owner_name = $row['name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO flat_booking         (post_id,owner_mobile,owner_name,buyer_mobile,buyer_name) VALUES         ('$post_id','$owner_mobile','$owner_name','$buyer_mobile','$buyer_name')";
if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo "Success";
 }
 else{
 echo "error";
 }
mysqli_close($con);
}else{
echo 'error1';
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Maybe this:

> $owner_mobile = $row['mobile'];

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First thing that you're doing wrong is injecting unvalidate/unescaped user input directly into a SQL query..... use prepared statements/bind variables, and always assume that the user wants to SQL inject your system to delete your database

Comment: check my ans it's work

Comment: $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$owner_mobile = $row['mobile'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
$owner_mobile = $row['mobile'];
```

You have not created the `$row` variable. For this you would need to do something such as:

Do this first:

```
<?php
$row = array();
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $row[] = $result;
}
?>
```

This allows you to do this:

```
<?php
foreach ($row as $r)
{
    var_dump($r); print "<br />"; // One row from the DB per var dump
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table flatower and add mobile column    
$post_id = 1;
    $sql = "select mobile from flatowner where id='$post_id'";
    $res = mysql_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $owner_mobile = $row[0]['mobile'];
```

Comment: Care to add some explanation?